# How to keep the timezone offset of the utc dates with luxon?

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

I'm trying to print multiple dates that are stored with their own timezone off-set.

Using momentjs, I used to do the following

```js
const date1 = "2013-01-01T00:00:00-05:00";
const date2 = "2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00";

console.log(moment.parseZone(date1).format());
console.log(moment.parseZone(date2).format());

// 2013-01-01T00:00:00-05:00
// 2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00
```

which prints both dates with their offset (`-05:00` and `-13:00`).

I would like to do the same with luxon js

```js
const date1 = "2013-01-01T00:00:00-05:00";
const date2 = "2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00";

console.log(luxon.DateTime.fromISO(date1).toISO());
console.log(luxon.DateTime.fromISO(date2).toISO());

// 2013-01-01T02:00:00.000-03:00
// 2013-01-01T10:00:00.000-03:00
```

But instead of keeping the offset seems like it's converting them to `-03:00`.
How can I keep the same off set?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer. I need to activate the `setZone` option.
So, the solution will be as follow:

```js
const date1 = "2013-01-01T00:00:00-05:00";
const date2 = "2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00";

console.log(luxon.DateTime.fromISO(date1, { setZone: true }).toISO());
console.log(luxon.DateTime.fromISO(date2, { setZone: true }).toISO());

// 2013-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
// 2013-01-01T00:00:00.000-13:00
```

Check the doc [here](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones?id=setzone).

Comment: The Doc link is not available anymore.